# Take action on HTTP Post Request

Tags: php, c, linux, bash, http

I have a Webhook say http://example.com/revoke/script . Whenever a user HTTP POST's to this URL, I want to start a bash scrip with root privileges.
I had looked at calling system commands in **php** and **python**, but I have found out that invoking a script which requires root privileges , is very difficult.
Can you suggest me some best practices to achieve this?

Comment: Pretty sure the best practice is **Don't do it**. Find a way to achieve what you want without a script running as root.

Comment: @jku I must have to invoke a script on web call. I had figure out a way. Please look int answer, posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) for this purpose. By using incron you can select a directory to be watched and whenever this directory got updated, incron can take certain actions such as invoking a script.